# Linked list in C is not printing

Tags: c, linked-list

I think it is not printing because I am not inserting into the list correctly. I see most people allocate space outside of the loop, but I am not sure that is the case.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct intList {
    int number;
    struct intList *next;
} INT_LIST;

int main() {
    INT_LIST *start = NULL, *temp;
    INT_LIST *trvPtr = start;
    /* Insert into list */
    while (temp->number != 0) {
        temp = malloc(sizeof(INT_LIST));
        printf("Enter your integer: ");
        scanf("%d", &(temp->number));
        temp->next = start;
        start = temp;
    }
    printf("List is: \n");
    while (trvPtr != NULL) {
        printf("%d", trvPtr->number);
        trvPtr = trvPtr->next;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't initialize `temp` to point at anything, so `while (temp->number != 0)` invokes *undefined behavior*

Comment: Also your `trvPtr` is initialized to `NULL` and never changed afterwards, so your "print loop" never executes

Comment: a helpful tip to always remember - *Always initialize your variables*

Answer (score 2):

`temp` is uninitialized and points to garbage. Checking `temp->number != 0` is undefined behavior.

You can solve this with a do/while loop. The loop will always run once. Allocate `temp`, set it, then check.

```
    INT_LIST *start = NULL, *temp;
    do {
        temp = malloc(sizeof(INT_LIST));
        printf("Enter your integer: ");
        scanf("%d", &(temp->number));
        temp->next = start;
        start = temp;
    } while(temp->number != 0);
```

Note that your list will always start with a value of 0. To avoid this, check the input before doing anything else. Use `while(1)` for an infinite loop and use `break` to end the loop.

```
    INT_LIST *start = NULL;
    while(1) {
        int input;
        printf("Enter your integer: ");
        scanf("%d", &input);
        if(input == 0) {
            break;
        }

        INT_LIST *temp = malloc(sizeof(INT_LIST));
        temp->number = input;
        temp->next = start;

        start = temp;
    }
```

When you print, `trvPtr` will always be NULL; it will not track changes to `start`. You have to assign it to the new value of `start`.

```
    printf("List is: ");
    INT_LIST *trvPtr = start;
    while (trvPtr != NULL) {
        printf("%d ", trvPtr->number);
        trvPtr = trvPtr->next;
    }
    puts("");
```

Note that you're not limited to declaring all the variables at the start of the function.

Answer (score 0):

I have made some modifications/corrections in your code and the following should work -

### Correct Code -

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct intList {
    int number;
    struct intList *next;
} INT_LIST;

int main() {
    INT_LIST *start = NULL, *temp;
    temp = (INT_LIST*)malloc(sizeof(INT_LIST));
    INT_LIST *trvPtr = temp;
    /* Insert into list */
    do {
        
        printf("Enter your integer: ");
        scanf("%d", &(temp->number));
        start = temp;
        temp->next = (INT_LIST*)malloc(sizeof(INT_LIST));
        temp = temp->next;
        
    }while (start->number != 0);
    temp->next=NULL;

    printf("List is: \n");
    while (trvPtr->next != NULL) {
        printf("%d", trvPtr->number);
        trvPtr = trvPtr->next;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**SAMPLE OUTPUT :**

```
Enter your integer: 1
Enter your integer: 2
Enter your integer: 3
Enter your integer: 0
List is:
1230
```

If you don't want the 0 to be printed, include `temp = start`, right after the first while loop ends.

---

### Explanation :

1. Firstly, in your code, you hadn't assigned `temp` anything. It should have been allocated space and assigned something first or else the statement **`temp->number != 0` is just undefined behavior.**
2. Nextly, I have used `start` to check for the last value entered by the user. If it is 0, the loop will break. Do note I have converted the loop into `do-while` loop, since `start` is NULL at the beginning.
3. Lastly, once the loop ends, I have set the next of temp to null so that the printing loop will execute correctly. In your code, this part also had a mistake since you had assigned NULL to `trvPtr` but never changed the value. So, in your case, the loop would never have executed.

**NOTE :** It's always better to mention the cast-type explicitly while using malloc. Some compiler would give warnings/errors. So, I have modified that as well wherever you have used `malloc()`